# Strange PDO behavior

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm using the following code:

```
 try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }    
 try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM images");
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The code perfectly works, but when I edit my query to:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, description FROM images");
```

I obtain an empty result.

Obviously the **description** field exists. Obviously I tested the new query with PHPMyAdmin.

I found that:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
```

is **TRUE** and I also tried to change the **fetclAll** to **FETCH_BOTH**.

Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT: OK, I FOUND THE PROBLEM:**

In a record, in the column **description** there was a "è". If I delete the "è", all is perfectly working. Why this happening?

Comment: Have you looked at your error logs? What do the error logs say?

Comment: Where can I find the logs file?

Comment: The simplest way with PHP is to add the line `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your page, directly after your opening php tag `<?php`. Then if there are any errors in the PHP or when querying the DB, it'll show the errors.

Comment: Ok, there is no error, in fact the rowCount is > 0..

Comment: I just realized that the column `name` is using a reserved word in mysql. So when you are trying to query using that column you need to write the column like this: `table.name`. Try that to see if that helps. So your entire query will be: `"SELECT id, images.name, description FROM images"`.

Comment: The problem is not the **name** column, but the description one.

Comment: @Michael `name` is not reserved; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html. If it were reserved it would need to be in backticks.

Comment: @helloimyourmind what happens if you use `*` is it empty?

Comment: Still doesn't works, I already tried.

Comment: So anything addressing the description column fails even if not referenced directly?

Comment: Yes @chris85. I also tried to rename the column or to destro ad re-create the table but still doesn't works. In PHP My Admin, everything is ok.

Comment: @chris85 Funny enough, I referenced that link before typing what I did. Maybe it's case sensitive, then? Because the word `NAME` is in the table of Keyword and Reserved Words

Comment: It's not about name or case sensitive, the name are all in lower case, and if I do SELECT name from images, it works.

Comment: @Michael There's no `(R)` after `NAME` on that page. That means it's a keyword, but not a **reserved** word.

Comment: @helloimyourmind Is the code in the question a literal copy of your application? Make sure you only have one call to `fetchAll`; the first one reads all the results, the second one will return an empty remainder.

Comment: Guys, I repeat: if I only change the query, it's perfectly working. I think it's a fetchAll problem.

Comment: I thought the `fetchAll` worked when the `description` wasnt there?

Comment: Okay, so it wouldn't be the `fetchAll`. It sounds like something unique to your table/server..

Comment: Watch for my edit please, I found the problem.

Comment: The `è` is in the db, the PHP, or a columns value?

Comment: The "è" is a value of a record, in the **description** column.

Comment: See this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through and make sure you set the `charset` in the connection.

Comment: Yes, I solved with my solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was due to an accented letter in a record of the database.

The solution is the use of **`array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4")`** to set the character set of the connection to 'UTF-8 MultiByte 4' as follows:

```
  try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4"));
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
```

---

The reason this specific version of UTF-8 is used is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236).

Comment: You want to use `utf8mb4` ***not*** utf8 as MySQL utf8 is not true utf8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Martin thank you for the suggestion, I updated my answer.

Comment: You may also use `charset` in your dsn (first argument of PDO) to specify connection charset.